# Bootstrap 4 datepicker

Tags: datepicker, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to use datepicker https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html with Bootstrap 4.

Following the examples on above page, I can make it work with Bootstrap 3.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<main class="container">
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 100px">
        <div class="col">
            <input data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" id="datepicker">
        </div>
    </div>
</main>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        weekStart: 1,
        daysOfWeekHighlighted: "6,0",
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
    });
    $('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", new Date());
</script>
</body>
```

Using this code datepicker appears correctly.

But doing the same with Bootstrap 4:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous"></head>
<body>

<main class="container">
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 100px">
        <div class="col">
            <input data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" id="datepicker">
        </div>
    </div>
</main>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script type="text/javascript">
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        weekStart: 1,
        daysOfWeekHighlighted: "6,0",
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
    });
    $('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", new Date());
</script>
</body>
```

Makes it look less professional:

[image]

Looks like font and spacing are messed up in Bootstrap 4 version.

How can I get same look and feel of datepicker in Bootstrap 4?

Thanks

Comment: The title of the question was misleading to me. I thought it was related to an official bootstrap date picker, but it's just some third-party project.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can too override default datepicker classes like the following:

the default bootstrap font size is 1rem or 16px so update .datepicker class 
`font-size: 0.875em;` or/and update the cell width and height:

```
.datepicker td, .datepicker th {
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous"></head>
<body>

<main class="container">
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 100px">
        <div class="col">
            <input data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" id="datepicker">
        </div>
    </div>
</main>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style type="text/css">
        // solution 1:
        .datepicker {
            font-size: 0.875em;
        }
        /* solution 2: the original datepicker use 20px so replace with the following:*/
        
        .datepicker td, .datepicker th {
            width: 1.5em;
            height: 1.5em;
        }
        
    </style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        weekStart: 1,
        daysOfWeekHighlighted: "6,0",
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
    });
    $('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", new Date());
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I need to enable only today and previous 2 days .How to enable ?

Comment: How to enable time ?

Answer (score 4):

From documentation:

> bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.css

can be used to include the datepicker without depending on the Twitter Bootstrap library.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out `https://github.com/satyandra-softuvo/bootstrap4-datetimepicker`

```
$.extend(true, $.fn.datetimepicker.defaults, {
    icons: {
      time: 'far fa-clock',
      date: 'far fa-calendar',
      up: 'fas fa-arrow-up',
      down: 'fas fa-arrow-down',
      previous: 'fas fa-chevron-left',
      next: 'fas fa-chevron-right',
      today: 'fas fa-calendar-check',
      clear: 'far fa-trash-alt',
      close: 'far fa-times-circle'
    }   
});
```