# How to load a JS library in Blazor server razor file?

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, iife

I'm trying to follow the document [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to load [THIS](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/master/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js) bootstrap-datepicker within a blazor server app.  Note: I want to load it for a single page only without having to load it for all pages.

Within the .razor file I'm trying to do this:

**HTML**

```
<input @ref=ReferenceToInputControl class="form-control" id="obdInput">
```

**Code**

```
@code {
    ElementReference ReferenceToInputControl;
    private IJSObjectReference? jsModule;
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            jsModule = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/bootstrap-datepicker.js");
            await jsModule.InvokeVoidAsync("Datepicker", ReferenceToInputControl);
        }
    }

}
```

I get an error that "Could not find Datepicker.  Datepicker was undefined".

I've read so much information about IIFE and scope and closure and modules but I can't for the life of me figure out what I need to do with that function so it will load and I can use it to change the input into a calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That library isn't using ES Modules, so `import` won't work. The way it's distributed, it's designed to be loaded in a script tag:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

You'll also need the CSS from the same repo, as well as jQuery and Bootstrap.

However it's worth noting that that library is fairly old, does not have Bootstrap 5 support, and will need some adjustments to use with Bootstrap 3 or 4 [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49572786/bootstrap-4-datepicker).